# How to display hidden objects in editing mode？

Tags: edit-mode, shortcut

I follow the tutorial to make a model, in editing mode, the demonstrator can press H to show the hidden face, but I can't... Version 2.80

Thanks

Comment: hide = h unhide=alt + h check it out

Comment: .. and hide unselected is shift+ h